# Categories and functors

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbf{Top}$ be the category of topological spaces. We know that a morphism $f$ in some category is called a $\it{monomorphism}$ if, for any two morphisms $g_{1}$ and $g_{2}$ that can be precomposed with $f$, $fg_{1}=fg_{2}$ implies $g_{1}=g_{2}$. Similarly, $f$ is called an $\it{epimorphism}$ if, for any two morphisms $g_{1}$ and $g_{2}$ that can be post-composed with $f$, $g_{1} \cdot f=g_{2} \cdot f$, implies $g_{1}=g_{2}$.

I have to show that a continuous map $f:X \to Y$ is a monomorphism  in $\mathbf{Top}$ if and only if $f$ is injective.

Now, for continuity can we use the fact that the inverse image of open sets is open? Any hints or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Continuity is the hypothesis, you only need to show "injective$\iff$ monomorphism". Do you need a hint?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f$ is injective. Take maps $g_1$, $g_2$ with $fg_1=fg_2$. Now apply the forgetful functor from **Top** to **Set** and get the same equality looking at $fg_1$ and $fg_2$ as maps of sets. Since injective maps in **Set** are exactly monomorphism, we get that $g_1=g_2$.

Conversely, suppose $f\colon X\to Y$ is a monomorphism and assume it's not injective. Then there are $p,q\in X$ with $p\neq q$ such that $f(p)=f(q)$. Now consider the subspace $\{p,q\}\subseteq X$ with the induced topology. Take $g_1$ as the inclusion $\{p,q\}\to X$ and $g_2$ as the constant map $\{p,q\}\mapsto p$. Then $fg_1=fg_2$ but $g_1\neq g_2$, contradiction.

Comment: For the "only if" statement,  when assuming f is injective, applying the forgetful functor, where is injectivity needed? And why when applying the forgetful functor from Tops to Sets, we get the same equality? Clever argument for the latter proof though!

Comment: Injectivity is needed in order to cancel $f$ in Set. You get the same equality because "applying the forgetful functor" is a fancy way to say "look at $f,g_1,g_2$ as maps of sets".